# Defaults in multiple config files in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to define defaults in multiple config files, for the sake of organization and not having a huge config file. From what I can tell it doesn't work and the documentation doesn't mention anything about it but wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Here are both the config files:

_config.yml

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      value1: "Value1"
```

_config2.yml

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      value2: "Value2"
```

Here is an HTML file in the default directory

```
---
---
<p>{{ page.value1 }}</p>
<p>{{ page.value2 }}</p>
```

And here is the build command

```
jekyll build --config "_config.yml,_config2.yml"
```

With all of that, building the project generates the following for index.html

```
<p></p>
<p>Value2</p>
```

Even with changing the scopes it has the same result. It seems as though defining defaults in another config file will completely override defaults in the previous file. Is there a way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options) say:

> Specify config files instead of using _config.yml automatically. Settings in later files override settings in earlier files.

In your case the `default`'s `scope.path` is the key, and the values are overwritten because the `scope.path` is identical in both config files. If you changed the `path` in one file you should see both values appear.

Comment: I did try that. I tested it with putting index.html into a directory, changing the scope of one to that directory and keeping the scope of the other as empty/all and it had the same result.

Comment: But did you change the value of `path`? If not, nothing will work the way you want.

Comment: Yes, sorry, by changing the scope I meant I changed scope.path